# Found multiple lockfiles for ? What to delete?

Tags: node.js, json, package

Debug run script and I get this error. Do I delete the whole folder? If not how can I tell which lockfiles to delete?

**(Using npm as the preferred package manager. Found multiple lockfiles for c:\Users\Desktop\Downloads\create-10k-nft-collection-2.0.0.  To resolve this issue, delete the lockfiles that don't match your preferred package manager or change the setting "npm.packageManager" to a value other than "auto".)**

Comment: If you're using Yarn, delete `package-lock.json`. If you're using NPM, delete `yarn.lock`.

Answer (score 1):

for a quick fix, you just have to delete the `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` in your project folder.

**BUT**

This is probably because you are using a different package manager than the project. So the **best advice would be that you switch your package manager to use the same that was used to build the project**.

Eg: if the project originally contained `yarn.lock` file, then use `yarn` as a package manager and vice-versa.